Advanced String Calculator with asin, acos, atan Functions in C++
This is a follow-up question for Advanced String Calculator in C++. Considering the suggestions mentioned in MrBean Bremen's answer, I am trying to update the implementation as below.
The experimental implementation

StringCalculator class
class StringCalculator
{
    public:           
        StringCalculator(const std::string& input)
        {
            input_string = input;
        }

        long double get_result()
        {
            if(result == std::nullopt)
            {
                auto input_without_space = remove_spaces(input_string);
                auto braces_levels = get_braces_levels(input_without_space);
                auto braces_level_max = *max_element(braces_levels.begin(), braces_levels.end());
                while(braces_level_max > 0)
                {
                    std::size_t inner_braces_start = 0;
                    std::size_t inner_braces_end = 0;
                    if(braces_levels[0] == braces_level_max)
                    {
                        inner_braces_start = 0;
                    }
                    for(std::size_t index = 1; index < braces_levels.size(); ++index)
                    {
                        if( braces_levels[index - 1] == braces_level_max - 1 &&
                            braces_levels[index] == braces_level_max)
                        {
                            inner_braces_start = index;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    for(std::size_t index = inner_braces_start; index < braces_levels.size(); ++index)
                    {
                        if(braces_levels[index] == braces_level_max)
                        {
                            inner_braces_end = index;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(input_without_space.substr(inner_braces_start + 1, inner_braces_end - inner_braces_start - 1) == "")
                    {
                        throw std::runtime_error("Empty content in braces");
                    }
                    StringCalculatorHelper sch(input_without_space.substr(inner_braces_start + 1, inner_braces_end - inner_braces_start - 1));
                    input_without_space.replace(
                        inner_braces_start,
                        inner_braces_end - inner_braces_start + 1,
                        std::format("{:.20f}", sch.get_result()));
                    braces_levels = get_braces_levels(input_without_space);
                    braces_level_max = *max_element(braces_levels.begin(), braces_levels.end());
                }
                StringCalculatorHelper sch(input_without_space);
                result = sch.get_result();
            }
            return result.value();
        }
    private:
        std::optional<double> result;
        std::string input_string;
        constexpr std::vector<int> get_braces_levels(std::string_view input)
        {
            std::vector<int> braces_levels;
            int braces_level = 0;
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < input.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(input[index] == '(')
                {
                    braces_level = braces_level + 1;
                }
                braces_levels.emplace_back(braces_level);
                if(input[index] == ')')
                {
                    braces_level = braces_level - 1;
                }
            }
            if(braces_level!=0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Braces unbalanced");
            }
            return braces_levels;
        }

        //  copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/83481/6667035
        std::string remove_spaces(std::string str) 
        {
            std::string::iterator end_pos = std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
            str.erase(end_pos, str.end());
            return str;
        }
};


StringCalculatorHelper class
class StringCalculatorHelper
{
    public:           
        StringCalculatorHelper(const std::string& input)
        {
            input_string = input;
        }

        long double get_result()
        {
            if(result == std::nullopt)
            {
                numbers.clear();
                operators.clear();
                //  remove spaces
                auto input_without_space = remove_spaces(input_string);
                parse(input_without_space);
                while(operators.size() > 0)
                {
                    perform_computing();
                }
                result = numbers[0];
            }
            return result.value();
        }
    private:
        std::optional<double> result;
        std::string input_string;
        std::vector<long double> numbers;
        // define operators as enums
        enum class Operator
        {
            add,
            subtract,
            multiply,
            divide,
            pow,
            abs,
            sqrt,
            log,
            sin,
            cos,
            tan,
            cot,
            sec,
            csc,
            sinh,
            cosh,
            tanh,
            asin,
            acos,
            atan
        };

        std::vector<Operator> operators;

        // define basic operator strings with corresponding enums
        constexpr static std::pair<std::string, Operator> basic_op_names[] = {
            {"+", Operator::add },
            {"-", Operator::subtract },
            {"*", Operator::multiply },
            {"/", Operator::divide },
            {"^", Operator::pow },
        };

        // define advanced operator strings with corresponding enums
        constexpr static std::pair<std::string, Operator> advanced_op_names[] = {
            {"asin", Operator::asin },
            {"acos", Operator::acos },
            {"atan", Operator::atan },
            {"sinh", Operator::sinh },
            {"cosh", Operator::cosh },
            {"tanh", Operator::tanh },
            {"abs", Operator::abs },
            {"sqrt", Operator::sqrt },
            {"log", Operator::log },
            {"sin", Operator::sin },
            {"cos", Operator::cos },
            {"tan", Operator::tan },
            {"cot", Operator::cot },
            {"sec", Operator::sec },
            {"csc", Operator::csc },
        };

        constexpr void print_operator(Operator op)
        {
            switch (op)
            {
                case Operator::sqrt:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sqrt";
                    break;
                case Operator::abs:
                    std::cout << "Operator::abs";
                    break;
                case Operator::log:
                    std::cout << "Operator::log";
                    break;
                case Operator::sin:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sin";
                    break;
                case Operator::cos:
                    std::cout << "Operator::cos";
                    break;
                case Operator::tan:
                    std::cout << "Operator::tan";
                    break;
                case Operator::cot:
                    std::cout << "Operator::cot";
                    break;
                case Operator::sec:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sec";
                    break;
                case Operator::csc:
                    std::cout << "Operator::csc";
                    break;
                case Operator::sinh:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sinh";
                    break;
                case Operator::cosh:
                    std::cout << "Operator::cosh";
                    break;
                case Operator::tanh:
                    std::cout << "Operator::tanh";
                    break;
                case Operator::asin:
                    std::cout << "Operator::asin";
                    break;
                case Operator::acos:
                    std::cout << "Operator::acos";
                    break;
                case Operator::atan:
                    std::cout << "Operator::atan";
                    break;
                case Operator::add:
                    std::cout << "Operator::add";
                    break;
                case Operator::subtract:
                    std::cout << "Operator::subtract";
                    break;
                case Operator::multiply:
                    std::cout << "Operator::multiply";
                    break;
                case Operator::divide:
                    std::cout << "Operator::divide";
                    break;
                case Operator::pow:
                    std::cout << "Operator::pow";
                    break;
            }
        }

        constexpr void parse(std::string_view input_string)
        {
            std::string single_number = "";
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < input_string.size(); ++index)
            {
                for (const auto& op : advanced_op_names)
                {
                    if(input_string.substr(index, op.first.size()) == op.first)
                    {
                        operators.emplace_back(op.second);
                        index += op.first.size();
                        if(single_number == "")
                        {
                            single_number = "0";
                        }
                        numbers.emplace_back(std::stold(single_number));
                        single_number = "";
                    }
                }

                if(std::isdigit(input_string[index]) || input_string[index] == '.' || input_string[index] == ',')
                    single_number = single_number + input_string[index];

                for (const auto& op : basic_op_names)
                {
                    if(input_string.substr(index, 1) == op.first)
                    {
                        operators.emplace_back(op.second);
                        if(single_number == "")
                        {
                            single_number = "0";
                        }
                        numbers.emplace_back(std::stold(single_number));
                        single_number = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            if(single_number == "")
            {
                single_number = "0";
            }
            numbers.emplace_back(std::stold(single_number));
        }

        constexpr void perform_computing()
        {
            //  level 0 computation: 0-
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(operators[index] == Operator::subtract && numbers[index] == 0 && numbers[index + 1] != 0)
                {
                    numbers[index] = -numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }

            //  level 1 computation: advanced functions
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                bool operatorFound = true;
                switch (operators[index])
                {
                    case Operator::sqrt:
                        numbers[index] = std::sqrt(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::abs:
                        numbers[index] = std::abs(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::log:
                        numbers[index] = std::log(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::sin:
                        numbers[index] = std::sin(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::cos:
                        numbers[index] = std::cos(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::tan:
                        numbers[index] = std::tan(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::cot:
                        numbers[index] = 1 / std::tan(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::sec:
                        numbers[index] = 1 / std::cos(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::csc:
                        numbers[index] = 1 / std::sin(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::sinh:
                        numbers[index] = std::sinh(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::cosh:
                        numbers[index] = std::cosh(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::tanh:
                        numbers[index] = std::tanh(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::asin:
                        numbers[index] = std::asin(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::acos:
                        numbers[index] = std::acos(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::atan:
                        numbers[index] = std::atan(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        operatorFound = false;
                        break;
                }
                if (operatorFound)
                {
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }

            }

            //  level 2 computation: ^ (power)
            for(std::size_t rIndex = operators.size(); rIndex > 0; --rIndex)
            {
                std::size_t index = rIndex - 1;
                if(operators[index] == Operator::pow)
                {
                    numbers[index] = std::pow(numbers[index], numbers[index + 1]);
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }

            //  level 3 computation: * (multiplication) and / (division)
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(operators[index] == Operator::multiply)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] * numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
                if(operators[index] == Operator::divide)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] / numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }
            //  level 4 computation: + (addition) and - (subtraction)
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(operators[index] == Operator::add)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] + numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
                if(operators[index] == Operator::subtract)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] - numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        constexpr void reduce_operators_and_numbers(std::size_t index)
        {
            reduce_operators(index);
            reduce_numbers(index);
        }

        constexpr void reduce_operators(std::size_t index)
        {
            for(std::size_t index1 = index; index1 < operators.size() - 1; ++index1)
            {
                operators[index1] = operators[index1 + 1];
            }
            operators.resize(operators.size() - 1);
        }

        constexpr void reduce_numbers(std::size_t index)
        {
            for(std::size_t index1 = index; index1 < numbers.size() - 2; ++index1)
            {
                numbers[index1 + 1] = numbers[index1 + 2];
            }
            numbers.resize(numbers.size() - 1);
        }

        //  copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/83481/6667035
        std::string remove_spaces(std::string str) 
        {
            std::string::iterator end_pos = std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
            str.erase(end_pos, str.end());
            return str;
        }
};



Full Testing Code
The full testing code:
//  Advanced String Calculator with asin, acos, atan Functions in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

//  From https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264642/6667035
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) \
    M_Assert_Helper(#Expr, Expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, Msg)
#else
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) ;
#endif

void M_Assert_Helper(const char* expr_str, bool expr, const char* file, int line, std::string msg)
{
    if (!expr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Assert failed:\t" << msg << "\n"
            << "Expected:\t" << expr_str << "\n"
            << "Source:\t\t" << file << ", line " << line << "\n";
        abort();
    }
}

struct recursive_print_fn
{
    template<std::ranges::input_range T>
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& input, const int level = 0) const
    {
        T output = input;
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
        std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
            [&](auto&& x)
            {
                std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
                return x;
            }
        );
        return output;
    }

    template<std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& input, const int level = 0) const
    {
        T output = input;
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
        std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
            [&](auto&& element)
            {
                return operator()(element, level + 1);
            }
        );
        return output;
    }
};

inline constexpr recursive_print_fn recursive_print;

class StringCalculatorHelper
{
    public:           
        StringCalculatorHelper(const std::string& input)
        {
            input_string = input;
        }

        long double get_result()
        {
            if(result == std::nullopt)
            {
                numbers.clear();
                operators.clear();
                //  remove spaces
                auto input_without_space = remove_spaces(input_string);
                parse(input_without_space);
                while(operators.size() > 0)
                {
                    perform_computing();
                }
                result = numbers[0];
            }
            return result.value();
        }
    private:
        std::optional<double> result;
        std::string input_string;
        std::vector<long double> numbers;
        // define operators as enums
        enum class Operator
        {
            add,
            subtract,
            multiply,
            divide,
            pow,
            abs,
            sqrt,
            log,
            sin,
            cos,
            tan,
            cot,
            sec,
            csc,
            sinh,
            cosh,
            tanh,
            asin,
            acos,
            atan
        };

        std::vector<Operator> operators;

        // define basic operator strings with corresponding enums
        constexpr static std::pair<std::string, Operator> basic_op_names[] = {
            {"+", Operator::add },
            {"-", Operator::subtract },
            {"*", Operator::multiply },
            {"/", Operator::divide },
            {"^", Operator::pow },
        };

        // define advanced operator strings with corresponding enums
        constexpr static std::pair<std::string, Operator> advanced_op_names[] = {
            {"asin", Operator::asin },
            {"acos", Operator::acos },
            {"atan", Operator::atan },
            {"sinh", Operator::sinh },
            {"cosh", Operator::cosh },
            {"tanh", Operator::tanh },
            {"abs", Operator::abs },
            {"sqrt", Operator::sqrt },
            {"log", Operator::log },
            {"sin", Operator::sin },
            {"cos", Operator::cos },
            {"tan", Operator::tan },
            {"cot", Operator::cot },
            {"sec", Operator::sec },
            {"csc", Operator::csc },
        };

        constexpr void print_operator(Operator op)
        {
            switch (op)
            {
                case Operator::sqrt:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sqrt";
                    break;
                case Operator::abs:
                    std::cout << "Operator::abs";
                    break;
                case Operator::log:
                    std::cout << "Operator::log";
                    break;
                case Operator::sin:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sin";
                    break;
                case Operator::cos:
                    std::cout << "Operator::cos";
                    break;
                case Operator::tan:
                    std::cout << "Operator::tan";
                    break;
                case Operator::cot:
                    std::cout << "Operator::cot";
                    break;
                case Operator::sec:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sec";
                    break;
                case Operator::csc:
                    std::cout << "Operator::csc";
                    break;
                case Operator::sinh:
                    std::cout << "Operator::sinh";
                    break;
                case Operator::cosh:
                    std::cout << "Operator::cosh";
                    break;
                case Operator::tanh:
                    std::cout << "Operator::tanh";
                    break;
                case Operator::asin:
                    std::cout << "Operator::asin";
                    break;
                case Operator::acos:
                    std::cout << "Operator::acos";
                    break;
                case Operator::atan:
                    std::cout << "Operator::atan";
                    break;
                case Operator::add:
                    std::cout << "Operator::add";
                    break;
                case Operator::subtract:
                    std::cout << "Operator::subtract";
                    break;
                case Operator::multiply:
                    std::cout << "Operator::multiply";
                    break;
                case Operator::divide:
                    std::cout << "Operator::divide";
                    break;
                case Operator::pow:
                    std::cout << "Operator::pow";
                    break;
            }
        }

        constexpr void parse(std::string_view input_string)
        {
            std::string single_number = "";
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < input_string.size(); ++index)
            {
                for (const auto& op : advanced_op_names)
                {
                    if(input_string.substr(index, op.first.size()) == op.first)
                    {
                        operators.emplace_back(op.second);
                        index += op.first.size();
                        if(single_number == "")
                        {
                            single_number = "0";
                        }
                        numbers.emplace_back(std::stold(single_number));
                        single_number = "";
                    }
                }
                
                if(std::isdigit(input_string[index]) || input_string[index] == '.' || input_string[index] == ',')
                    single_number = single_number + input_string[index];
                
                for (const auto& op : basic_op_names)
                {
                    if(input_string.substr(index, 1) == op.first)
                    {
                        operators.emplace_back(op.second);
                        if(single_number == "")
                        {
                            single_number = "0";
                        }
                        numbers.emplace_back(std::stold(single_number));
                        single_number = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            if(single_number == "")
            {
                single_number = "0";
            }
            numbers.emplace_back(std::stold(single_number));
        }

        constexpr void perform_computing()
        {
            //  level 0 computation: 0-
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(operators[index] == Operator::subtract && numbers[index] == 0 && numbers[index + 1] != 0)
                {
                    numbers[index] = -numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }
            
            //  level 1 computation: advanced functions
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                bool operatorFound = true;
                switch (operators[index])
                {
                    case Operator::sqrt:
                        numbers[index] = std::sqrt(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::abs:
                        numbers[index] = std::abs(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::log:
                        numbers[index] = std::log(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::sin:
                        numbers[index] = std::sin(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::cos:
                        numbers[index] = std::cos(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::tan:
                        numbers[index] = std::tan(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::cot:
                        numbers[index] = 1 / std::tan(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::sec:
                        numbers[index] = 1 / std::cos(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::csc:
                        numbers[index] = 1 / std::sin(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::sinh:
                        numbers[index] = std::sinh(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::cosh:
                        numbers[index] = std::cosh(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::tanh:
                        numbers[index] = std::tanh(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::asin:
                        numbers[index] = std::asin(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::acos:
                        numbers[index] = std::acos(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    case Operator::atan:
                        numbers[index] = std::atan(numbers[index + 1]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        operatorFound = false;
                        break;
                }
                if (operatorFound)
                {
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
                
            }

            //  level 2 computation: ^ (power)
            for(std::size_t rIndex = operators.size(); rIndex > 0; --rIndex)
            {
                std::size_t index = rIndex - 1;
                if(operators[index] == Operator::pow)
                {
                    numbers[index] = std::pow(numbers[index], numbers[index + 1]);
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }
            
            //  level 3 computation: * (multiplication) and / (division)
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(operators[index] == Operator::multiply)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] * numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
                if(operators[index] == Operator::divide)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] / numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }
            //  level 4 computation: + (addition) and - (subtraction)
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(operators[index] == Operator::add)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] + numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
                if(operators[index] == Operator::subtract)
                {
                    numbers[index] = numbers[index] - numbers[index + 1];
                    reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        constexpr void reduce_operators_and_numbers(std::size_t index)
        {
            reduce_operators(index);
            reduce_numbers(index);
        }

        constexpr void reduce_operators(std::size_t index)
        {
            for(std::size_t index1 = index; index1 < operators.size() - 1; ++index1)
            {
                operators[index1] = operators[index1 + 1];
            }
            operators.resize(operators.size() - 1);
        }

        constexpr void reduce_numbers(std::size_t index)
        {
            for(std::size_t index1 = index; index1 < numbers.size() - 2; ++index1)
            {
                numbers[index1 + 1] = numbers[index1 + 2];
            }
            numbers.resize(numbers.size() - 1);
        }

        //  copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/83481/6667035
        std::string remove_spaces(std::string str) 
        {
            std::string::iterator end_pos = std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
            str.erase(end_pos, str.end());
            return str;
        }
};

class StringCalculator
{
    public:           
        StringCalculator(const std::string& input)
        {
            input_string = input;
        }

        long double get_result()
        {
            if(result == std::nullopt)
            {
                auto input_without_space = remove_spaces(input_string);
                auto braces_levels = get_braces_levels(input_without_space);
                auto braces_level_max = *max_element(braces_levels.begin(), braces_levels.end());
                while(braces_level_max > 0)
                {
                    std::size_t inner_braces_start = 0;
                    std::size_t inner_braces_end = 0;
                    if(braces_levels[0] == braces_level_max)
                    {
                        inner_braces_start = 0;
                    }
                    for(std::size_t index = 1; index < braces_levels.size(); ++index)
                    {
                        if( braces_levels[index - 1] == braces_level_max - 1 &&
                            braces_levels[index] == braces_level_max)
                        {
                            inner_braces_start = index;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    for(std::size_t index = inner_braces_start; index < braces_levels.size(); ++index)
                    {
                        if(braces_levels[index] == braces_level_max)
                        {
                            inner_braces_end = index;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(input_without_space.substr(inner_braces_start + 1, inner_braces_end - inner_braces_start - 1) == "")
                    {
                        throw std::runtime_error("Empty content in braces");
                    }
                    StringCalculatorHelper sch(input_without_space.substr(inner_braces_start + 1, inner_braces_end - inner_braces_start - 1));
                    input_without_space.replace(
                        inner_braces_start,
                        inner_braces_end - inner_braces_start + 1,
                        std::format("{:.20f}", sch.get_result()));
                    braces_levels = get_braces_levels(input_without_space);
                    braces_level_max = *max_element(braces_levels.begin(), braces_levels.end());
                }
                StringCalculatorHelper sch(input_without_space);
                result = sch.get_result();
            }
            return result.value();
        }
    private:
        std::optional<double> result;
        std::string input_string;
        constexpr std::vector<int> get_braces_levels(std::string_view input)
        {
            std::vector<int> braces_levels;
            int braces_level = 0;
            for(std::size_t index = 0; index < input.size(); ++index)
            {
                if(input[index] == '(')
                {
                    braces_level = braces_level + 1;
                }
                braces_levels.emplace_back(braces_level);
                if(input[index] == ')')
                {
                    braces_level = braces_level - 1;
                }
            }
            if(braces_level!=0)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Braces unbalanced");
            }
            return braces_levels;
        }

        //  copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/83481/6667035
        std::string remove_spaces(std::string str) 
        {
            std::string::iterator end_pos = std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
            str.erase(end_pos, str.end());
            return str;
        }
};

//  From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686/6667035
constexpr bool AreSame(double a, double b, int tolerance) {
    return std::fabs(a - b) < tolerance * std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
}

constexpr auto testExpression(std::string input_expression, long double expect_result, int tolerance)
{
    StringCalculator sc1(input_expression);
    M_Assert(
        AreSame(sc1.get_result(), expect_result, tolerance),
        input_expression + " test case failed");
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    testExpression("-12.3456 + 2 ^ 3 * 3.123", 12.6384, 1);
    testExpression("-0.12345 * 3 - 5", -5.37035, 1);
    testExpression("1024*2+2048*4", 10240, 1);
    testExpression("10-2*3+2*2-7", 1, 1);
    testExpression("1+(2+(3+4))+2+3", 15, 1);
    testExpression("1+sin(1)", 1.841470984807897, 10);
    testExpression("1+sin(2^2)", 0.243197504692072, 10);
    testExpression("1+cos(2^(2+2))", 0.042340519676615, 10);
    testExpression("1+tan((1+2)*3)", 0.547684340558190, 10);
    testExpression("1+cot(tan((1+2)*3))", -1.057976196110096, 10);
    testExpression("1+sec(cot(tan((1+2)*3)))", -1.136132630785074, 10);
    testExpression("2+3*csc(-2)", -1.299250510883849, 10);
    testExpression("2 * sqrt(3) + 1", 4.464101615137754, 10);
    testExpression("2 * sqrt(abs(-3)) + 1", 4.464101615137754, 10);
    testExpression("4^3^2", 262144, 10);
    testExpression("log(4^3)", 4.158883083359671, 10);
    testExpression("sinh(-1)", -1.175201193643801, 10);
    testExpression("cosh(sinh(-1))", 1.773775678340353, 10);
    testExpression("tanh(cosh(-1))", 0.912636575963212, 10);
    testExpression("tanh(-1)", -0.761594155955765, 10);
    testExpression("asin(sin(-10))", 0.575222039230620, 10);
    testExpression("acos(cos(-1))", 1, 10);
    testExpression("tan(atan(-1))", -1.000000000000000, 10);
    testExpression("tan(atan(-1)^2)", 0.709164626405133, 10);
    testExpression("asin(sin(-3)^2)", 0.019916173286866, 10);
    testExpression("tanh(cosh(-1)+tanh(cosh(-2)))", 0.987686168952949, 10);

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}

The output of the test code above:
Computation finished at Mon May 13 15:47:44 2024
elapsed time: 0.00106393

Godbolt link is here.
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
Advanced String Calculator in C++

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to follow the suggestions mentioned in MrBean Bremen's answer to implement an advanced string calculator with more function support in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
Please review the implementation of StringCalculator and StringCalculatorHelper class and its tests.



It is inefficient
Your code is very inefficient for various reasons. First, StringCalculator itself only handles braces. It finds the innermost braces, then uses StringCalculatorHelper to parse the expression inside those braces, and then textually replaces the part of the expression in the innermost braces with the result of its evaluation, and that is being done repeatedly until only one value is left.
Second, copies are made of the input string in various places, for example each instance of StringCalculator and StringCalculatorHelper will store a copy of the string passed to its constructor.
Third, in parse() you are testing every position in the input string against every possible operator. A much better way would be to tokenize the input first, then just use a std::unordered_map() to efficiently check if the token matches one of the operator names.
Finally, in perform_computing() you loop multiple times over the parsed list of operators, and each time you find a matching one you perform a single operation and then return, so get_result() has to call it multiple times until no operators are left. You should be able to make it so you can continue after performing a single operation.
Avoid repeating yourself
One of the worst things you can do in programming is repeating the same code over and over again. It's time consuming to write such code, it is easy to make mistakes, and it makes refactoring your code a lot harder.
Whenever you repeat the same pattern three or more times, I recommend you immediately stop and find a way to reduce the amount of code duplication to a minimum. Consider for example the "level 1 computation":
case Operator::sqrt:
    numbers[index] = std::sqrt(numbers[index + 1]);
    break;
case Operator::abs:
    numbers[index] = std::abs(numbers[index + 1]);
    break;
case Operator::log:
    numbers[index] = std::log(numbers[index + 1]);
    break;
…

There is a clear pattern here. Identify what is the same and what is different. Find a way to turn the thing that is always the same into a function or something else that can be reused. For example, the above could be simplified using a macro:
#define HANDLE_OPERATOR(op) \
case Operator::op: \
    numbers[index] = std::op(numbers[index + 1]); \
    break;

HANDLE_OPERATOR(sqrt)
HANDLE_OPERATOR(abs)
HANDLE_OPERATOR(log)
…

Avoid using macros though unless there really is no other choice. Also, I cheated a bit here because this breaks down once you get to Operator::cot. A better option here would be to make a map from operator to the actual operation:
std::unordered_map<Operator, std::function<double(double)>> operator_actions = {
    {Operator::sqrt, [](double x){ return std::sqrt(x); }},
    {Operator::abs,  [](double x){ return std::abs(x);  }},
    {Operator::log,  [](double x){ return std::log(x);  }},
    …
}

There is a little bit more repetition there, but without macros it is unavoidable. Still, now you can write the following in perform_computing():
// level 1 computation: advanced functions
for(std::size_t index = 0; index < operators.size(); ++index)
{
    if (auto action = operator_actions[operators[index]])
    {
        numbers[index] = action(numbers[index + 1]);
        reduce_operators_and_numbers(index);
        return;
    }
}

Issues with precision
When you are textually replacing a subexpression with its result, you use std::format("{:.20f}", …). This can however lead to a severe loss of precision. First, C++ makes no guarantee about the actual precision of long double. On the Intel architecture, it might be that long double is 80 bits, if it is stored in FPU registers. However, there are other architectures where long double is 128 bits, so 20 digits is not enough.
But an even bigger problem is that floats can store values that are much smaller than 0.00000000000000000001. By using .20f, you are truncating those small values. Much better would be to format using scientific notation: .20e. But even better would be to not do any text replacement at all, but parse expressions in such a way that partial results are always stored in long doubles.
This shouldn't be a class
Unlike Java, in C++ not everything has to live in a class. Instead of StringCalculator, you could just make a free function named calculate(), which takes a string as input and returns the result. The member variables you currently have can just become local variables in calculate().
Consider implementing a Pratt parser
If you want to implement a more capable, more efficient and more elegant parser, I recommend you split your code into a tokenizer and a parser. The tokenizer's job is just to find numbers, operators and keywords (like sqrt, log and so on) in the input. This simplifies the parser a lot. There are then still various ways you can build a parser, but one that is quite elegant to write is a Pratt parser.
